# ScrollViewer inside (Stack-)Panel

Tags: wpf

I'm fighting with a ScrollViewer inside a StackPanel. The ScrollViewer only shows one scrollbar depending on the StackPanel's orientation, what I kind of understand as the StackPanel thinks to be unlimited in that direction. I therefore tried to limit the size of the ScrollViewer by binding it to the StackPanel's width and height. When the application is brought up it shows both scrollbars but they do not resize properly. What is wrong or how should I do it.

(Remark: I know I can use a Grid instead of the StackPanel and the ScrollViewer behaves as expected. However once I place that Grid into a StackPanel the problem shows up again.)

```
<Window x:Class="tt_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
<StackPanel x:Name="sp" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ScrollViewer
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        Width="{Binding ElementName=sp, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=sp, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Button Background="LightCoral" Width="500" Height="500">Hey</Button>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a grid then? What special property of the StackPanel do you need?

Comment: I want to have a control (that includes a ScrollViewer and) that I can use in various places, among them in a StackPanel.

Comment: You should really be using another panel type. A StackPanel tries to minimize it's own size. You want your element to fill the panel. Don't fight the StackPanel, chose a panel that actually does what you want. Maybe a DockPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Scroll viewer is useless inside a vertical StackPanel. A vertical StackPanel has its height set to infinity, so the ScrollViewer has all the size it wants and will never show the scrollbar. You should switch to a Grid or DockPanel.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, i solved it by switching stackpanel and scrollviewer.

Comment: I know that, but I want to have a control that I can use in a StackPanel.